# Batch : change tab delimited to pipe delimited

Tags: batch-file, csv

Edit Question:

Now, i can change from tab to pipe delimited. But the data have space after text. How to add code in bat to trim space?

Original Question :

I want to create nightly batch process to change text file that seperate by tab delimited to pipe delimited.
And if the data have space after text. how to trim the space?

Before :

FileName : Customer_Tab.pwf --> that is text file

Data that seperate column by tab delimited:

```
Customer Number Customer Name   Partner Number  Partner Name    Customer Country

1ABC    Jame    1234    Anny    USA

2DEF    Susan   5678    Prissy  UK
```

Convert to data that seperate by pipe delimited

FileName : Customer_Pipe.csv

Data :

```
Customer Number|Customer Name|Partner Number|Partner Name|Customer Country

1ABC|Jame|1234|Anny|USA

2DEF|Susan|5678|Prissy|UK
```

Please help me to create batch.

I don't know how to create batch for this question.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Batch is a poor choice for modifying text files. It is overly complicated to get a robust solution, and it is slow. But it can be done.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

set input="Customer_Tab.pwf"
set output="Customer_Pipe.csv"

::There should be a TAB character after the equal below
set "tab=   "

>%output% (
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /rn "^" %input%') do (
    set ln=%%A
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "ln=!ln:*:=!"
    if defined ln set "ln=!ln:%tab%=|!"
    echo(!ln!
    endlocal
  )
)
```

The solution will read both Unix (`<LF>`) and Windows style (`<CR><LF>`) lines. The output will be Windows style lines.

The only limitation to the above is each line must be < ~8k in length.

The `tab` variable is not necessary. I used it to make it more obvious what the code is doing.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean batch as in Windows, the easiest way is to probably head on over to the [GnuWin32 packages page](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) and pick up a copy of `sed`.

Then you can simply replace tabs with pipe symbols with something like:

```
sed "s/\t/|/g" inputfile >outputfile
```

Or, if you don't mind getting your hands dirty with a little C coding:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc (stdin)) != EOF)
        putchar ((ch == '\t') ? '|' : ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling that program `tab2pipe.c` into the executable `tab2pipe` will allow you to run it as:

```
tab2pipe <inputfile >outputfile
```

Answer (score 2):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
del Customer_Pipe.csv
for /f "delims=" %%i in (Customer_Tab.pwf) do (
    set line=%%i
    >> Customer_Pipe.csv echo !line:    =^|!
)
```

There's a tabulation character after `!line:` in the last line

Comment: i tried to run this batch but output data are not change from tab delimited to pipe delimited. what should i do. Because i'm amateur to do in batch and programming. T-T

Comment: There's a tabulation character after !line: in the last line

??
after !line: --> i use tabulation in batch file but result is the same as initial file. They're not change from tab to pipe.

please advice.

Comment: Upload your original file and the bat file that you're trying to execute.

Comment: i can't upload original file because...

new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: This bat will not work if either your original file or bat file do not contain tab character. Posting here doesn't help because tabs are not retained.

Comment: Yeah Yeah Yeah YeaH!!!!!!!!!!!

i tried to use tab again.
now, it's OK.

Many thanks again and again.
Thank you for your kindly.

Comment: And a little bit to disturb. if the data have space after data such as 

123   

how to trim this data?

Comment: This solution will corrupt any lines that contain `!` characters. It will also strip blank lines. This may or may not be a problem, depending on the input.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this through a batch file, but if you have php installed on your system you could use simply call a small php script from your batch file like this:

```
 [convert.batch]
 php -f covert.php

 [convert.php]
 <?php
 // read entire file into an array
 $rows = file('Customer_Tab.pwf');
 // create output file
 $fp = fopen('Customer_Pipe.csv', 'w');
 foreach($rows as $row) {
   // replace tabs with pipes
   $data = str_replace("\t", "|", $row);
   // write formatted row to output file
   fwrite($fp, $data);
 }
 fclose($fp);
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you to all of you for your kind. But i still not convert from tab delimited to pipe delimited. Because i'm amatuer for batch and coding. i'm still waiting for your help. T_T

Answer (score 0):

Open the tab delimited file in Notepad

Delete quote marks (`"`) at the start and end of each line, if there are any. Plus any single word at the very very top, above what you might consider column headers... they will both throw off the column header recognition when opening the file again later

Open **Microsoft Word** in *'punctuation view'* (by clicking that blobby thing that looks like a musical symbol on the top toolbar)

In Word, type a "tab" space and you will see an arrow pointing to the right. copy it to clipboard

In Notepad, choose *edit->replace* and paste the tab mark in the 'find what' field and put the pipe symbol in the 'replace with' field and choose 'replace all'

Job done.
Save file as `*.txt` but prefix it with the word `pipe` so you know which one it is in the folder. Open it in **Excel** as `*.txt` file, using pipe as the deliminator in *'other'* and unchecking the tab checkbox.